# Проблема со сборкой в Vue Cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, build, vue-cli

Я уже давно знаю html css js, привык к определенной структуре папок, к подключению библиотек через cdn. Но недавно приступил к изучению vue. Я использую vue-cli.

**Описание вопроса**: я не  понимаю, как присоединяются компоненты *vue* к *index.html* (точка входа), зачем-то vue записывает все компоненты в *js* файл, которые после рендерятся браузером. Но если посмотреть на итоговый *index.html* там вообще ничего нет. Хотя в документации vue говорится, что компоненты – основной принцип работы фреймворка. Также я анализировал некоторые сайты написанные с использованием *vue*, у всех главный (index.html) файл наполнен контентом изначально. А *vue-cli* пихает это все в *js* файл.

**Вопрос**: Почему это происходит? Какие настройки нужно включить в *vue.config.js*, чтобы все компоненты также собирались в index.html?

Вот какой index.html получается в итоге

[image]

Итоговая сборка проекта

[image]

Компонентов достаточно много, но почему-то index.html почти пустой

[image]

Вот для сравнения *index.html* с сайта *behance.net* в этом очень много строк и его не назовешь пустым

[image]

файл main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;


new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  render: h => h(App)
});
```

файл App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <BeginPresentation/>
    <Tables/>
    <EndForm/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import BeginPresentation from './components/BeginPresentation/BeginPresentation.vue'
  import Tables from './components/Tables/Tables'
  import EndForm from './components/EndForm/EndForm';



  export default {
    name: 'App',

    data: function(){
      return {

      }
    },

    components: {
      BeginPresentation,
      Tables,
      EndForm
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="sass">
  @import "./main.sass"
</style>
```

Если не сложно, дайте пожалуйста более подробный ответ на вопрос. Может кто-то ещё интересуется этой темой.
**Спасибо**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Vue.js**, когда вы создаете приложение и билдите его, оно бандлится в один app.js файл, так как **Vue.js** это полностью **Javascript**.
Если вы хотите получать готовую разметку, вам нужно смотреть на SSR - отрисовка на стороне сервера или генерация статики. Как пример - **[Nuxt.js.](https://nuxtjs.org/)**

Цитата из [источника](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html):

> [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) — это высокоуровневый фреймворк, построенный на экосистеме Vue, что обеспечит быстрое получение опыта разработки универсальных приложений на Vue. И даже лучше, вы можете использовать его в качестве генератора статических сайтов (со страницами представленными однофайловыми компонентами)! Мы настоятельно рекомендуем попробовать его.